# "Prevent of" vs "prevent from"?

Tags: prepositions

> The Iraqi government prevented these NGOs from having major influence
> within the country.

> The Iraqi government prevented these NGOs of having major influence
> within the country.

Are both sentences correct? Why do I I sometimes see "prevent of" instead of "prevent from"?

Comment: "How come I sometimes see "prevent of" instead of "prevent from"?" - because you sometimes see mistakes?

Comment: on research papers?

Comment: Writers of research papers are not immune from basic errors, and these may be more numerous if the researcher's main subject is not English.

Comment: Errors in text may arise from lack of English knowledge or certainty, or from failure to check text for typing errors after writing it. Writing 'I I' instead of 'I' is an example of that.

Answer (score 2):

> Are both sentences correct?

No - only the 1st.

> How come I sometimes see "prevent of" instead of "prevent from"?

I don't know. Please give links to some examples.